# How to store socket object in google app engine Datastore (aka can I pickle a socket object)

Tags: python, sockets, google-app-engine, pickle, google-app-engine-python

I need to store a Socket object into datastore/memcache in a GAE Python based app.

The approach I am taking is to 
1. Use pickle.dumps to convert the socket object into a string 
2. When it is needed retrieve this string and unpickle it using `pickle.loads(<pickledSock>)`

Complete error message below, but the main part is:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument '_sock'
```

Does this mean I can't use above approach because the "unpickling" won't work?

```
ssl_sock2Use=pickle.loads(pickledSock)
File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1382, in loads
    return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 858, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1217, in load_build
    setstate(state)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_dist/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 181, in __setstate__
    self.__init__(_sock=_sock)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument '_sock'
```

Comment: `pickle` can't serialize a `socket`, however the `dill` pickler can.  `dill` has run in google app engine, but I don't know about Datastore.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. When I try to deploy app with  import dill, it fails. I tried to include the dill.py form source code but that is also seeing a  failure (trying to access /dev/null). I am going to try commenting out some lines and including all files in source.  In case, you know of simpler way to get dill to work on GAE, pls let me know. I also tried including it as library in app.yam but I got an error saying library dill is not supported.

Comment: Ah, I guess then `dill` is not currently working on GAE.  Here's a link to the PR for GAE.  https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill/pull/1. It should be a simple as commenting out a few lines for the offending objects on GAE.  Not an optimal solution, but I know I've seen `dill` be used to pickle a `socket` on GAE, so...

Comment: If you find that this isn't working and you'd like it to, and can't find anything in the documentation which makes reference to whether it isn't possible, feel free to file a feature request or issue report in the [public issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-platform/).

Comment: Filed @ https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12429